# Android Facebook login works in debug, doesn't work in published app

Tags: android, facebook-login, parsefacebookutils

I have an Android app that has Facebook login. I've tested number of times on my device (it has Facebook app installed, if it helps) and login works flawlessly. I've submitted my app to Play Store, and users can't login with Facebook in release version. I've noticed that even I have Facebook app installed, there is a web browser window with something like Facebook login page displayed split second, it disappears, and my activity indicator (which should stop and go to next activity upon login) spins forever.

I am using Parse 1.9.1 and ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1 and I login using ParseFacebookUtils using:

`ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground`

The same user, the same user, everything is the same. In debug mode, it just logs in, but in release it doesn't, and I don't know why and I can't debug. What are the possible causes and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `Key Hash` settings on https://developers.facebook.com for your app. You need to have both key hashes for release and debug version set in app developer console. It might be that you've just set the key hash for the debug environment. For more see [Setting a Release Key Hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash). Hope it helps.

Comment: That was it, I've added the release key hash and I can login now.